# Intercepting all orders with full data in MT4

Tags: c++, mql4

I'm trying to write a trade copier for MT4. I have already written one for MT5, but the issue I'm having with translation is in intercepting active orders. In MT5, this is relatively simple:

```
void OnTradeTransaction(const MqlTradeTransaction &trans, const MqlTradeRequest &request, 
   const MqlTradeResult &result) {
   // Code goes here
}
```

As shown in the [MQL5 documentation](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/runtime/event_fire#tradetransaction), this event intercepts all orders sent from the client and accepted by a trade server.

Looking at the MQL4 documentation, however, I don't see any easy way of doing this. The closest I could get would be to iterate over all the orders by doing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < OrdersTotal(); i++) {
    if (!OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS)) {
       // Error handling here
    }

    // Do stuff with this order
}
```

My understanding is that this code also gets all open orders. However, the issue I'm having is that there are key pieces of information that I cannot determine on these orders:

1. Slippage
2. Position-by (for close-by orders)
3. Action type (close, close-by, delete, modify, send). Although this could be inferred from the fields populated on the order.

In my mind, I could then go and intercept the orders when they're generated (i.e. wrap `OrderClose`, `OrderCloseBy`, `OrderDelete`, `OrderModify` and `OrderSend`) and pull the relevant information off of the orders that way. But that still doesn't cover the case where the user enters an order manually.

Is there a way I can intercept all orders data without losing information?